# setting up the PAB - could not start the plutus-chain-index

Tags: plutus, plutus-pioneer-program, pab

I'm trying to follow [the lesson 6 of iteration 3 of the plutus-pioneer-program](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X6AyZIZ0vaE&list=PLNEK_Ejlx3x2sBWXHdFBRgkzPF6N-1LVi&index=9)

when trying to start che chain index trough the command (fromn the [plutus-apps repository](https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-apps))

```
plutus-chain-index --config ./plutus-pab/test-node/testnet/chain-index-config.json  --socket-path $CARDANO_NODE_SOCKET_PATH start-index
```

the following error raises

```
plutus-chain-index: user error (autoMigrate: Not performing automatic migration due to data loss)
```

I'm assuming is unable to find the database, so I also tried to specify the `cardano-node` db folder but the following error is raised

```
plutus-chain-index: SQLite3 returned ErrorCan'tOpen while attempting to perform open "<cardano-node db folder>": unable to open database file
```

so I tried ot specify a brand new path, but got

```
plutus-chain-index: SQLite3 returned ErrorCan'tOpen while attempting to perform open "./tmp/chain-index.db": unable to open database file
```

#### does anyone knows how to correctly start the chain index?